# Handling an 'Error: Generic Exception' in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, error-messages, filters

How would you solve this issue?
When I try filtering my data extension holding all my subscribers using a StoreID to filter for subscribers relating to a specific store I get the **Error: Generic Exception**

I'm clueless about why this happens.
I've created numerous data extensions like this before, and I've also saved them in the destination folder before without problems.
There is really no obvious reason for this error occurring.

What would your next step to solving an issue like this be; how would you turn that error message into something you can relate to?

Thank you

[image: Error as shown in Marketing Cloud]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some scenarios SFMC is not perfect. This case from that pool as well. Relation ships and filtering is a bit dodgy. The quickest solution would be to Create a support ticket with High Level and Explain in details you issue with screenshots. Provide access to your instance. I believe, support will not come back to you in 2-3 hour, hence escalate it and you get immediate action

Comment: Thank you, the description of having this solved with Support is helpful -> therefore the acceptance. I managed to solve the problem without support, though. Apparently, the role for that user had been changed and the Interactions/filters boxes had been unchecked in the role settings.
I noticed more users with the same roles starting reporting this issue, and I examined the role instead of that particular user and business unit, which led me to finding this :)